# Преобразовать YCbCr в YCbCr jpeg?

Tags: c++, c, jpeg, кодек

Я не могу понять пару вещей, и одно исходит из другого.

Как представлен цвет YCbCr в памяти? 
В случае, допустим, RGB565 все понятно, 16 бит это один пиксель (RRRRR GGGGGG BBBBB)

Но я не могу понять как представляется в памяти YCbCr 422 который  приходит с цифровой камеры.

Например (я вообще не уверен, что это правильно):

1 байт - Y

2 байт - Cb

3 байт - Cr

Ещё куда-то надо деть второй Y так как Cb и Cr у них двоих один

Так же не понимаю, что касается YCbCr у JPEG, ведь там цвета кучкуются в 8х8 пикселей. Я правильно понимаю, что у них один Cb и Cr, и каждый свой Y? Как эти данные представлены в памяти?

От сюда мой главный вопрос, я накапливаю данные одного кадра с камеры (OV2640) в формате YCbCr 422 и скармливаю их JPEG кодеку и получаю фигню.
Я слышал, что будет легче если получать данные в YCbCr, чем преобразовывать из RGB. Но выходит сырые YCbCr данные тоже нужно "подготовить" для JPEG кодека?

Будет ли это быстрее преобразования из RGB? Можно ли где-то посмотреть код этого преобразования?

Comment: 422 обозначает [subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) В данном случае цветоразностные каналы передаются в половину горизонтального разрешения. Как они упакованы - это другой вопрос.  Обычно используется планарный YCbCr (то бишь отдельные массивы компонент друг за другом).

Comment: Да, и зачем их скармливать JPEG? Для виде есть более подходящие кодеки.

Comment: Про YCbCr  я уже хорошо начитался, вопрос остался именно в том, ка кон упакован. А на счет видео, у меня выбора нет, вот и JPEG